# Enemy in Digger game needs to move by itself, code is breaking and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, multithreading, compiler-errors, artificial-intelligence

In my csse class we are making a Digger game http://www.futrega.org/digger/, and so far we have completed these functions for our game 
• Levels    loading from    files 
• A hero    that    can pick    up  emeralds    for points and  move 
• Switching between loaded levels   with U and D. 
Right now I am working on making the Hobbin move by itself(it is the enemy that eats through dirt and other items) towards the hero and changing the lives of the hero, this is the code that I have so far for it's move function.

```
public void move(){
    int Hero_x = Level.hero.myLocation.getX();
    int Hero_y = Level.hero.myLocation.getY();
    int X = this.myLocation.getX();
    int Y = this.myLocation.getY();
    int speed = 2;
    int x_distance =  Hero_x - X;
    int y_distance = Hero_y - Y;
    double distance = Math.hypot(x_distance, y_distance);
    this.x_velocity = (int) ((speed/distance) * x_distance);
    this.y_velocity = (int) ((speed/distance) * y_distance);
    while(Level.map[X + this.x_velocity][Y + this.y_velocity] instanceof Hero == false) {
        Level.map[X][Y] = new Tunnel(new Coordinate(X, Y));
        if ((X + this.x_velocity) < 0 || (X + this.x_velocity) > this.MAP_WIDTH - 1) {
            this.myLocation.setCoordinate(X, Y);
            Level.map[X][Y] = this;
        } else if ((Y + this.y_velocity) < 0 
                     || (Y + this.y_velocity) > this.MAP_HEIGHT - 1) {
            this.myLocation.setCoordinate(X, Y);
            Level.map[X][Y] = this;
        } else {
            this.myLocation.setCoordinate(X + this.x_velocity, Y + this.y_velocity);
            Level.map[X + this.x_velocity][Y + this.y_velocity] = this;
        }
    }
    if(World.lives == 0) {
        new Main().launch();
    }
    World.lives = World.lives - 1;
    Level.hero.myLocation.setCoordinate(Level.hero.myLocation.getX(),
                                             Level.hero.myLocation.getY());
    Level.map[Level.hero.myLocation.getX()][Level.hero.myLocation.getY()] = Level.hero;
    this.myLocation.setCoordinate(this.Location.getX(), this.Location.getY());
    Level.map[this.myLocation.getX()][this.myLocation.getY()] = this;
}
```

Basically what it does is that it gets its X and Y velocity(I searched on google and this was the answer given on how to make the enemy follow a player, but I don't know if this is right) and then it checks if the enemies next position is an instance of the Hero and if it is not then I implemented code that just makes it move and if it is past the bounds of the screen then it doesn't move. And then if the while statement is broken(the next position of the Hobbin is an instance of Hero) then it checks if the lives = 0 and if it does then it restarts, but if it doesn't then it subtracts a life and it sets the hero and the hobbin back to their original locations, keeping the dirt and everything else on the board the same though. I put the

```
new Thread(hobbin).start();
```

In the constructor of the level, I think that should make the hobbin run correctly when a new level is made.
I am getting this error when I run the code however,

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Hobbin.draw(Hobbin.java:71)
    at Level.paintComponent(Level.java:82)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

could someone explain this? And if my code is wrong could someone explain how? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

I notice that you are concerned with your AI code breaking your program, but that doesn't look to be the case in the error report. Notice that the null pointer exception that you are receiving is in the hobbin.draw function during a paintComponent call for during the graphics call phase of your game.

The odds are stacked towards the actual error being a relative path string like "/mycoolpictures/hobbinframespritesheet.png" being mis referenced or mis spelled... so that your image loader gets a null picture from a file not found error, but tries to pass it on into your game anyways... and then DOOOOM of hobbin.

Hope this helps.

Comment: See thats what I was thinking that the draw function was messed up but I have not added any sprites to it yet, and before I added the move function it was working fine, it would load the game perfectly and play perfectly so idkk :/ perhaps something is out of bounds and is causing the map to not draw correctly thus this error? I would vote up but I got no reps

Comment: You are right actually something is wrong with the draw function causing it to give an error but i honestly have no idea what

Comment: oh, well... check line 71? there is a variable that it is trying to munch on... and it's null... and it can't be null for your Hobbin class.  soo... line 71 should be in the draw method, btw...